# Determine if expiry date is 12 days away from current date

Tags: datetime, go, time

I am using time package in Go. I am trying to return a boolean "True" if expiry date is 12 days away from current date.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    expirydate, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04 MST", "2020-09-30 20:57 UTC")
    if err != nil {
        // ...
        return
    }

    delta := time.Now().Sub(expirydate)
    fmt.Println(delta)
 
}
```

this above code returns a duration. Unable to convert it to date and return a boolean.

https://play.golang.org/p/I0vw7IDvdXj

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot compare the duration to the duration of 288 hours = 12 days? What is your question?

Comment: Show actual code that's doing an actual comparison. Then explain the problem you're having. Your code doesn't do what you're describing as it stands.

Comment: are you looking for [time.Before](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Before)?

Comment: "Unable to convert it to date" - of course you can't. "12 days" isn't a date, it's a duration. You have the correct type for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler just to make a date by subtracting 12 days from your expiry, then check if time.Now() is after that date (returns a boolean).

If you have a given expiry date, you can find 12 days before with AddDate, then you can compare that to another time to check if that time is after it with now.After.

```
expiresSoon := now.After(expiry.AddDate(0, 0, -12))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/D9sLqrdBX5k